# Python/KivyMD: How to print the text from a MDTextField that is inside an MDScreen in python/kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Hi i'm fairly new to kivymd and i'm trying to print the text that a user inserts in a MDTextField that is inside a screen when pressing a button. Normally I'd use **self.screen.ids.name_of_id.text** to get access to the text from the .py file however that doesn't seem to work when using screens and gives the error **AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'**. Is there a way to get access to the text from the .py file?

my .kv snippet

```
ScreenManager:
    ForgotPassword:
    Login:
    ResetPassword:
    Main:

<ForgotPassword@Screen>
    name: "forgot"
    MDFloatLayout:

        MDTextField:
            id: forgot_email
            hint_text: "Email"
            size_hint: .7, None
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "                Requesitar Nova Password                "
            md_bg_color: 0, 0.4, 1, 1
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            font_size: 16
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .15}
            on_press: app.forgot_password()
```

my .py code

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "500"
        self.screen = Builder.load_file("Backup.kv")
        return self.screen

    def forgot_password(self):
        print(self.screen.ids.forgot_email.text)



MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `self.screen` in your `print()` statement is the `ScreenManager`, which, in your case, will have no `ids`, causing the error. The `ids` are only available in the root of each rule in the `kv`. So, in your `kv`, only `ScreenManager` and `ForgotPassword` can have `ids`. But no `ids` are defined in the `ScreenManager`, so it will have no `ids`. The `forgot_email` is defined under the `ForgotPassword` rule, so that `id` will appear in the `ids` of the `ForgotPassword` `Screen` instance. So, to access that `MDTextField`, try:

```
def forgot_password(self):
    print(self.screen.get_screen('forgot').ids.forgot_email.text)
```